# iTunes Connect (localized), We're temporarily unable to save your changes. Please try again later

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

I want to add the new **+ localized** languages in My Apps

i receive this error near one week for all apps and i can't adding new languages in my app.

**We're temporarily unable to save your changes. Please try again later.**

Comment: Are you using Safari browser? Safari works better for Itunes Connect.

Comment: Yes I use Safari 
and I try with Mozilla but doesn't work

Comment: Actually Chrome works best, I know that makes 0 sense, but anything I have issues with iTunesConnect with app submissions I just reopen in Chrome and it works.

Comment: Thanks , but with Chrome doesn't work  too now for me

Comment: Use the "Contact Us" link in iTunes Connect and report the issue to Apple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add localized languages, delete all the ScreenShots that came across from the first language, (even if they are the same ones that you intend to use) then reload them all again.

(Use the delete all ScreenShots - when you enter the new language page!!!)

Comment: emphasis on "All" Localized Images of All sizes to be removed.